# Httpd/Mysqld timeout a lot

Tags: timeout, fedora, apache, mysql

I'm using Fedora 14 and httpd timeout a lot.

Is there a log or something that tell me how many connnections to httpd and mysqld every second/minutes...etc

I'm very new to linux, please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can view the Access Log in httpd to see requests:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

May be different for your version:
[Access Log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html#accesslog)

Or if the established session is timing out too early, set `KeepAlive` and `KeepAliveTimeout`:

[KeepAlive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#keepalive)

[KeepAliveTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout)